# Radgrid Column total at footer when auto generate column is true

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I need to show Row total at footer when dynamic generate columns is true in Telerik radgrid.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_OnNeedDataSource"> <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="true"> </MasterTableView> </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I need to show Row total at footer when dynamic generate columns is true in Telerik radgrid.

Comment: Tony Vitabile  , Do you have answer ?

Comment: How can I have an answer? I don't know what the question is because you didn't ask it.

Comment: Clearly mentioned my question , In telerik radgrid I need to show Column total values at footer  when Auto generate column mode is true, Anyone can't ask clearly furthermore this ....

Comment: @Sasikumar, you forgot to post the code you have as well as your attempts at solving the problem. It's not too late to do that.

Comment: <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true"
                                    OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_OnNeedDataSource">
                                    <MasterTableView  AutoGenerateColumns="true">
                                    </MasterTableView>
                                </telerik:RadGrid>

Comment: In My scenario, column not predefined in Mastertableview, it will be defined dynamically based on datasource, In that case I have mentioned AutoGenerateColumns is true, So I need to show Column total at footer row.

Comment: @Sasikumar.prs, You want to display total for all column or for specific column.

Comment: @jayesh Goyani, I need for all column, But the column will be generated dynamically...thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
    OnColumnCreated="RadGrid1_ColumnCreated">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="true"></MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object source, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        RadGrid1.ShowFooter = true;
    }
}

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
        new { ID = 1, Name ="Name1"},
        new { ID = 2, Name ="Name2"}
    };
    RadGrid1.DataSource = data;
}

protected void RadGrid1_ColumnCreated(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.DataType.Name == "Int32")
    {
        GridBoundColumn bndcol = (GridBoundColumn)e.Column;
        bndcol.Aggregate = GridAggregateFunction.Sum; 
    }
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Great Answer! Thanks a lot  @Jayesh Goyani